# Why do I get ‘Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.’ error when I use JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable, jsondecoder

(unknown context at $10741e078).CodingKeys>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil)

my model is ,

```
struct Details : Decodable {

    var userInfo : RequestUserInfo
    var commercialInfo : String?

}

struct RequestUserInfo : Decodable {

    var UserName : String?
    var Email : String?
    var UserIdentity : String?
    var UserMobile : String?
    var ThirdName : String?
    var LastName : String?
    var IdIssueDate : String?
    var IdSourceCity : String?


}
```

(unknown context at $10741e078).CodingKeys>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil)

Comment: add the code and api..

Comment: please post json and models

Comment: I have posted the json and the models

Comment: For future, include the error in your question’s title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to mark the types as **`Optional (?)`** wherever you're expecting `null` in the JSON.

But, the issue with the above parsing is different from the one you described in the question.

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "newRequest", intValue: nil),
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: "parcels", intValue: nil),
>   _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "UsingPurposeId", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to
>   decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

This can be resolved like so,

The type of `UsingPurposeId` in `BuildingRequestParcelDetails` must be `Int?` instead of `String?`

Parse the data in following way,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BuildingRequestDetails.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I am parsing this way only . Please check my question. I am still getting error .

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the same JSON. Because with this json and changing to 
Int?, it is working perfectly at my end.

Comment: I've checked with your JSON and @PGDev answer - everything works correctly

Comment: yes i am getting this JSON . I have copied and pasted it here

Comment: i used Int? itself

Answer (score 1):

In your case this may happens if 
Details.userInfo == nil

set

```
var userInfo : RequestUserInfo?
```

And your error will disappear.
But in fact your error hides in wrong data. Try before decoding add string:

```
print(String(data:  data, encoding: .ascii))
```

and check carefully is anything is ok. 
For example, you may get "user_info" instead key "userInfo"

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `ModelAPI` - https://app.quicktype.io?share=NYC0PgFnypeo5cLho3sH
and call it with code `self.requestDetail = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelAPI.self, from: json)`. I've checked and it works. Also, I've fixed your JSON (error with two lines)

Comment: The error description pretty much says it all: "Cannot get keyed decoding container — found null value instead". Now I check your model, also, as I wrote - "Invalid JSON variable". Give a few minutes - check it.

Comment: I have fixed the issue in JSON .

Comment: why should i change that?

Comment: `struct BuildingRequestParcelDetails : Decodable` has property `var UsingPurposeId : String?`. You should replace it with `var UsingPurposeID : String?`. When I changed - everything worked correctly. And @PGDev is right - you can just change the type to `Int?` and then everything will work too

Answer (score 0):

If you are JSON decoding to a Codable object mapped to Core Data then you can use a do try method. For example with an object which may have a set of names.

```
    do {
        names = NSSet(array: try 
        container.decode([Name].self, forKey: .names))
    } catch {
        print("no names found")
    }
```

If no names are within the JSON then no names found will be printed and the JSON decoder won't return an error